# Overwrite CSS styles with no styles

Tags: html, css

I have a div within a tag. The a tag has certain styles like color etc, which are also applied to the div tag. I do not want the styles of a tag to be applied to the div tag. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: you need to show your code

Comment: post code on jsbin or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned this is how CSS works, child inherits properties of its parents and if you don't want inherited property, you have to manually override.

But, there is small feature, special value [auto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/auto) value - if you use id for valid property eg. `width` that element won't get inherited value, but default calculated by browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/G3WUw/

### HTML

```
<div class="general">
    <div>
        Width set to 200px by general rule<br>
        Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
    </div>
    <div class="special1">
        Width set to 300px by specific rule<br>
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="special2">
        Width set to default value calculated by browser<br>
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.general div {
    background: lightgreen;
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 200px;  
}

.general .special1 {
    width: 300px;
}
.general .special2 {
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how CSS (**cascading** style sheets) work. You would need to do.

```
a div { color: #f00; }
```

To override the color you set on the parent `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

As the `<div>` tag is within the `<a>` tag, the CSS styles applied to the `<a>` tag will be inherited by the `<div>` tag.

You can simply apply a **CSS class** to the `<div>` tag which has the CSS styles that you need. So the class applied to the `<div>` tag will override the parent `<a>` tag styles.